# What does "->" do in PHP?

Tags: php

I am studying how to connect database while learning PHP. Just a quick question. Does anyone can tell me what does "->" sign do in PHP? I cannot understand the functionality of this sign so that I have no idea how to edit the code. Thank whoever answer this.

Comment: hi, this is not php 101, thanks

Comment: Nice one, bro. I get it. It's my Stackoverflow 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real quick and dirty one-liner anonymous objects, just cast an associative array:

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');

echo $obj->foo; // prints 'bar'
echo $obj->property; // prints 'value'

?>
```

... no need to create a new class or function to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3):

`->` Sign used in objects, to access it's property and methods.

```
class example{
    public $prop1 = 'Hello World';

    public function sayHello(){
        echo $this->prop1;
    }
}

$example = new example();
$example->sayHello();
```

Ref: [Classes and Objects in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 2):

-> Is Used to refer the Classes And Objects for more information check [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted any code, so I'm not 100% sure where you saw this, but I'm almost certain you are referring to something like this:

```
$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->bar;
```

In this example, `->` is used to access a property of an object, `$foo`. It can also be used to access a method, as in `$foo->baz();`.

Comment: tut, you should know this should just be closed and not answered ;-)

Comment: @Dagon It's certainly not a good, SO-worthy question. On the other hand, I'm sympathetic with OP just because it would be basically impossible for a true beginner to search for that syntax. Google, for example, wouldn't help much.

Comment: well actually if you put the exact question title in Google you get a great answer

Comment: @Dagon Huh. I stand corrected. Google usually isn't a lot of help with programming syntax, so I just assumed it wouldn't be helpful here.

Comment: @EdCottrell even in [php search](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=->&scope=quickref) it returns `-> doesn't exist. Closest matches:`